# Exported jar from Eclipse works on Linux but not Windows

Tags: java, cross-platform, swt, compatibility, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a program which I wrote in Eclipse on Ubuntu. I exported the program into a runnable .Jar and it works fine on Linux systems.  If I try to use it on a Windows system I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError related to two SWT .Dll files. I've been trying to open it by typing in the command line:

```
java -jar <filename>.Jar`
```

Is there a way I can pack these .Dll files into the runnable .Jar? I've never encountered this error before so I'm really not sure what to do. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: do you have eclipse on windows ? just to check

Comment: I do. To clarify the version of eclipse is 64bit and the version of Java is 64bit. I've attempted to open it on many different Windows computers which is why I feel it must be an issue with the way the .Jar is packed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using [SWTJar](http://mchr3k.github.com/swtjar/).

> SWT is a Java widget toolkit that provides access to native UI elements. This presents a problem when it comes to packaging an application as you need to include a different SWT jar for each platform (Windows/Linux/OSX)/(32/64bit). To support all of these standard platforms you have to build and distribute 6 different packages which isn't really in the spirit of Java's write once, run anywhere.

How it works:

> SWTJar is an ant task which allows you to build a single jar which loads the correct SWT classes at runtime allowing you to distribute a single jar which works across (Windows/Linux/OSX)/(32/64bit).

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem! :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it's the one you wanted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow [these steps](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program%3F). And based on how they are worded, it sounds like the runnable jar is only for a single target platform, although it can be any supported platform.

Comment: No text in that link you posted!

Comment: I think you're referring to this 

"Starting with Eclipse version 3.3, the file "swt.jar" file includes platform-specific executable files that are unpacked automatically when your SWT program is executed. This means that a given runtime folder will normally be platform specific. "

In that case it does sound like a runnable jar is platform specific. :(